# Elastic Beanstalk and Browserify

Tags: npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, browserify

I have an express app which is currently deployed on EB. I want to add a front-end to it which will require compile with babelify / browserify and minimization with uglify, the compilation would also use some env variables to define which api to call and authenticate against (staging vs production).

However I can't figure out how to install those as global packages on EB, I have tried .ebextensions with not much success, I am definitely missing something.

Any suggestion?

Comment: If this is for the front end, you should look into building it on your local machine and releasing directly to S3/cloudfront. Basically, your deployment script should release static files to s3 and server code to EB

Comment: I'd like to automate the process so that the front-end will be built based on the env variables on the machine. That way I'd lower the risk of mistakes in the deployment

Comment: Yes, I have a single script that does all of this on the build machine, so the release process is fully automated. But IMO, it is not a good idea for the EC2 machine to be both a production server and a build machine.